# MySQL query that gets all rows UNTIL the SUM(column) is bigger than X

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data

```
user_id   days   date
88        2      2013-08-25
88        4      2013-08-23
88        18     2013-08-5
88        1      2013-08-4
88        2      2013-08-2
73        11     2013-08-2
299       4      2013-08-2
12        983    2013-08-2
```

I'm trying to get all recent rows (`order by DATE desc`) for a specific user_id , until the SUM of `days` column is bigger than `X`. For example in this case if X=7 I would get the three first rows with SUM(days)=24.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. Here you will use a local variable that will count the sums in the subquery.

```
select
    user_id,
    days,
    date
from
    (
    select
        user_id,
        days,
        date,
        @sum_days := @sum_days + days as sum_days
    from
        myTable
    order by
        date desc
    ) t
    cross join (select @sum_days := 0) const -- resetting your @sum_days var.
where
    sum_days < X -- fill a number in for X here.
```

Comment: As a note:  So you can fit this in one query statement, you can change the inner `from` to `from MyTable cross join (select @sum_date := 0) const`.

Comment: You didn't use a `WHERE user_id=`. Should I it be in sub-query or outer query?

Comment: @Noam In the sub query

Comment: It seems to be the right direction, but actually not working, and just returning an empty set.

Comment: I had a typo in my answer. Somewhere I had `@sum_date` in stead of `@sum_days`. I fixed it.

Comment: It isn't working for me either, just returning an empty set.

Comment: @LeeHanKyeol try adding another variabel to act as row counter, and add an OR condition in the the last WHERE to always include the first row.